# How to start computer in safe mode?

Tags: windows-xp, safe-mode, bootrepair

I have an IBM thinkpad and suddenly when i turned it on it came up with an error message saying: \windows\system32\config\system is corrupt or missing.

I am trying to start it in safe mode but still I get the same error even if press F8. I have some important data and I don't want to loose that. It is my work laptop given by my office so does have CD drive and I dont access to bios.

Is it possible that can I repair OS without full format or installing a new window? It has windows XP and my data is in C: drive which is the OS drive.

What are the options to fix the problem and save my data. (I just want to save 2-3 doc files 4-5mb)

Answer (score 1):

The best answer in such cases is **restore needed files from your backup**. It's a lesson for you to start making them. Now, how to recover your files.

We don't know if your files are fine or corrupted, so we have to handle them with care or we can make things worse. Boot some LiveCD Linux distro, like Ubuntu or PartedMagic. Then mount your partition **read-only** to prevent Linux from writing anything to it. Here's a related question on AskUbuntu: [How to mount a hard disk as read-only from the terminal](https://askubuntu.com/q/296331/129094). Then use file manager to copy your files to a flash drive or external HDD. You can try to open them to verify if they are corrupted or not.

If you're unable to open recovered files or you see any error messages during that routine, then you should assume filesystem is corrupted and try to recover those files. [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) and [PhotoRec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec) are good free file recovery tools.

The worst case scenario is your files are corrupted and there's nothing you can do. So **make regular backups**.

Comment: Although this is technically correct, the answer is pretty technical and doesn't explain much. You might want to include some more details, such as what a LiveCD is and how to get one.